# How to pass python's variable output to psql?

Tags: python, psql

We have the 'var/www/html/x' file which has two lines.
x_read variable allows us to read just first line.
For example - when we want to save this line using this x_read, there are no issues.

Problem appears when we want to use x_read in our postgresql instruction. There are no errors like INTERNAL SERVER ERR or something, application goes on and works, but the value of x_read
is not saved in the database.

We've tried also with mysql and still there were random 'crashes', I mean - sometimes it works, sometimes not.

How to insert data from a python variable to a postgres instruction/table/select/etc.?

Here is the code:

```
read = open('/var/www/html/x', 'r')
x_read = read.readline()

mycursor.execute("insert into test (name, code, city, x, y) values ('xxx_wet', '00-000', 'xxx_city'," +"'"+ x_read +"'"+ ", '19.560');")
mydb.commit()
```

Comment: why not just use `f-strings` as: `f"insert into test (name, code, city, x, y) values ('xxx_wet', '00-000', 'xxx_city', '{x_read}' '19.560')"`

Comment: Hello, you can try like this:
`mycursor.execute("insert into test (name, code, city, x, y) values (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s);", ('xxx'wet', '00-000', 'xxx_city', x_read, '19.560'))`

Comment: We were using f' strings also - it doesn't matter - seems like psql does not see python var.

Comment: You could try @T0ny1234's suggestion or use `format()` as well: `"insert into test (name, code, city, x, y) values ( {}, {}, {}, {}, {} );".format('xxx_wet', '00-000', 'xxx_city', x_read, '19.560')`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should avoid when possible to insert values in a query string. It is now seen as poor practice because it has been used for decades for [SQL injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks. Parameterized query are much more resistant.

Next, readline leaves the terminating new line in the string which is probably not what you want.

Finally, `with` saves you to explicitely close a file.

Boiling it up together, it gives:

```
with open('/var/www/html/x', 'r') as read:  # ensure file will be closed
    x_read = read.readline().rstrip()       # clean up the end of the line

mycursor.execute("insert into test (name, code, city, x, y) values (?,?,?,?,?)",
                 ('xxx_wet', '00-000', 'xxx_city', x_read, '19.560'))
mydb.commit()
```

Comment: Thanks for the advices - it's just very poor code, because still psql is not listiening...

after implementation of your answer's solution, still there is no X (x_read). It's pretty sick, because I do not know why I can not just pass a string/text var to one instruction.

name | code |city | x | y
xxx_wet | 00-00 | | 19.560

Comment: @Osho You should use debugging traces (print) to control what `x_read` actually contains...

Comment: I don't think the best debugger is print :)
x file contains tw lines, such as 1) line first '11.111', 2) sec. line - '22.222''.
x_read.readline() reads only one of them as a string and it's ok at this level.
I cannot just pass output to postgre instruction. Very frustrating.
If you guys more details, please let me know - I will edit the post.